# Using def for matplotlib.pyplot - all data plotted, not what is passed to def

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I created a basic function to use with pyplot.

I have a csv(UTF8) file has the time and free memory statistics logged every 3 seconds for different file systems.

Here is my file structure:

```
time_seconds,filesystem_1_freemem,filesystem_2_freemem,filesystem_3_freemem
```

I am trying to plot freemem data different filesystem data for comparison.

I have the following code:

```
def draw_graph (input_file, x_axis, y_axis, label_color, label_name, graph_title):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = input_file.plot(kind="line")
    plt.title(graph_title)
    ax.set_xlabel("Time (seconds)")
    ax.set_ylabel("freemem")
    plt.ticklabel_format(style="plain", axis="y")
    plt.show
```

When I call this function with the following arguments, it draws *all* the data (filesystem_1_freemem, filesystem_2_freemem, filesystem_3_freemem), *not* the argument that I am passing it (filesystem_1_freemem):

```
draw_graph(df, "time_seconds", "filesystem_1_freemem" , "Red", "filesystem_1_freemem","Filesystem 1 - Freemem Values")
```

Obviously, there is something I am missing, so that it is plotting whatever is in the CSV file. How can I correct this?

After that, as an improvement, how can I revise the code so that it plots one (or multiple) argument(s) that it is given? (assume a for loop for the arguments?)

Thank you very much for your kind assistance!

Comment: You are passing `filesystem_1_freemem` as `y_axis`, but you never use it in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `pandas` as the "frontend" to `matplotlib`. `pandas` `df.plot.line()` method plots **all** Series (columns) in the given DataFrame.

Furthermore you pass alot of things to your function, but you never use any of the arguments. How is your code supposed to know which argument to use for which cause? There are lots of nice tutorials out there showing how to define functions in python.

To solve your current problem, you can try this code:

```
def draw_graph(input_file, x_axis, y_axis, label_color, label_name, graph_title):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = input_file.plot.line(x=x_axis, y=y_axis, color=label_color, label=label_name)
    plt.title(graph_title)
    ax.set_xlabel("Time (seconds)")
    ax.set_ylabel(label_name)
    plt.ticklabel_format(style="plain", axis="y")
    plt.show
```

Further improvements are:

```
def draw_graph (input_file, x_axis, y_axis, label_color, label_name, graph_title):
    ax = input_file.plot.line(x=x_axis, y=y_axis, color=label_color, label=label_name)
    plt.title(graph_title)
    ax.set_xlabel("Time in seconds")
    ax.set_ylabel(label_name)
    ax.ticklabel_format(style="plain", axis="y")
```

Short explanation:
Pandas already creates a figure instance on its own, so no need to create a second figure instance with `fig = plt.figure()`. But you could also create your own figure and pass its instance to pandas by:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
input_file.plot.line(ax=ax, ...)
```

`plt.show` is, depending on the backend etc., not needed in most cases.

Units shown in plots should be denoted without any braces. Best practice would be to write *Time* in italic and the unit in Roman, for example like `ax.set_xlabel(r'$Time$ $in$ $\mathrm{s}$')` (using the TeX frontend is imho the easiest solution, even though it looks quite cumbersome).
Even better is to combine this with a fraction bar instead of the word "in", for example like this: `ax.set_xlabel(r'$\frac{Time}{\mathrm{s}}$')`

Comment: Thanks very much Scotty!